# How to get .flr file from rive.app website?

Tags: flutter, flare, rive

i am new to rive animation and i noticed that rive.app website now allow use to download animation file in .rive format. It used to be .flr format. How do i get to download .flr again? Is this possible? thanks

Answer (score 1):

No you can't download .flr from rive now but you can use the rive flutter package to use .rive animations and it's also easy as for flare and even have for functionalities:- https://pub.dev/packages/rive